# C++ get off set position window

Tags: c++, mfc, cursor

Iam newbie in c++ programming and i was developing a application but am stuck at somewhere i want to get position a element in the window to simulate a mouse click.

I tried this but nowhere

```
POINT p;
if (GetCursorPos(&p))
{
   //cursor position now in p.x and p.y
}
```

This doesn't give the exact thing i want like if i move window to another position in windows it display wrong position.
But i want to get position of a button in the window when the user presses the Enter button.

Can someone help me.

Comment: I don't understand, you say you want to simulate a click in a specific button. So why are you getting the cursor position, when you would need to set it?

Comment: If you need to invoke a command, send a [WM_COMMAND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591.aspx) message. Simulating mouse clicks is usually the wrong solution to any problem.

Comment: @arainone This is application of hosting website and there is some problem with accepting some data so i just made a button but i want the user to be free until the process is complete so i want to invoke a click at that button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MFC, try this.

```
CPoint pos;

if( GetCursorPos(&pos) )
{
    ScreenToClient( &pos );
    TRACE("client pos: %d,%d\n", pos.x, pos.y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`GetCursorPos()` returns you the position of the cursor in screen coordinates.

If you want coordinates relative to the client area of your window, you can use [ScreenToClient function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Can you say a example lfor ScreenToClient function if i want to get the coordinate to use it for simulating click with this offset position?
First i will make a time to for getting the offset position to use it later. So how would i get the current offset position where the mouse is pointed.